how to solve this Bug in video controls html?
So I'm trying to embed more than 10 videos in the same page, they are preload="false" so it won't slow.
But I noticed that when i want to download one, I click in the "more options" kebab and it opens in the wrong video frame (the last one loaded actually), even when it downloads the correct video i clicked it on, just as if it opened up in the wrong position
Any help ?

I tried fixing this with css and positions but I cant' find how to manipulate the menu.
I'd like to find the css / js that controls this menu so i could fix the position or something.

Same problem Ubuntu 22.04.4 Google Chrome 125.0.6422.141
